# Can't find any python package after running cleaning cache

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, caching, package

I have been using python in VS Code for a while, everything was smooth. But yesterday I accidentally pressed "Run CC Cleaner" on my PC. This, among other things must have cleared some VS Code cache and I no longer can run scripts.

In cmd for example it says that "pandas can not be found" while pip says that it definitely is installed.

Running !python - m pip install pandas in VS Code just does not do anything.

Something must have severed the connection between python and VS Code.

Comment: You could try to access python from outside VS Code and copy the python path to the `launch.json` file inside your `.vscode` folder. In other words, type `which python` in a terminal window, then copy the path to `launch.json` like this `"env": "PYTHONPATH": "your/path/bin/python:lib"`

Comment: I don't have a launch.json file, it used to work without it

Answer (score 0):

The `Python` and the `Python Extension` do not have some connections, the `Python Extension` just needs to find the path of the `Python`.

It looks like an environment problem. Could you check which pip you are using with the command of `pip --version`?

But I was confusing of **python - m pip install pandas in VS Code just does not do anything**, could you explain it clearly?